# Boost speed optimizations,C++ operator overloading

Tags: c++, performance, overloading, simd

I am writing a part of the program where speed matters the most. In that part I am creating [color spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_space) like RGB and other. In-fact I wrote these 2 structs.

```
struct RGB {
    unsigned char r;
    unsigned char g;
    unsigned char b;
}

struct ARGB {
    unsigned char a;
    unsigned char r;
    unsigned char g;
    unsigned char b;
}
```

And I will have like 10 structs like this for different spaces and I have to do operator overloading for all of them, so I did something like this. I created a `struct ColorSpace<Type,Child>` here is the code

```
//
// Created by Hrant Nurijanyan on 01.12.20.
//
template<typename T, typename C>
struct ColorSpace {

    const T* cbegin() const { return static_cast<const C*>(this)->arr.cbegin(); }

    const T* cend() const { return static_cast<const C*>(this)->arr.cend(); }

    const T* begin() const { return cbegin(); }

    const T* end() const { return cend(); }

    T* begin() { return static_cast<C*>(this)->arr.begin(); }

    T* end() { return static_cast<C*>(this)->arr.end(); }

    [[nodiscard]] size_t size() const { return std::distance(begin(),end()); }

    const T& operator[](unsigned int i) const {
        return *(begin() + i);
    }

    T& operator[](unsigned int i) {
        return *(begin() + i);
    }

    C& operator=(const C& rhs) {
        std::copy(rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), begin());
        return static_cast<C&>(*this);
    }

    C& operator=(const T& rhs) {
        std::fill(begin(), end(), rhs);
        return static_cast<C&>(*this);
    }

    C operator+(const C& rhs) const{
        C result;
        std::transform(rhs.begin(),rhs.end(),begin(),result.begin(),std::plus<>());
        return result;
    }

    C operator-(const C& rhs) const{
        C result;
        std::transform(begin(),end(),rhs.begin(),result.begin(),std::minus<>());
        return result;
    }

    C operator*(const C& rhs) const{
        C result;
        std::transform(begin(),end(),rhs.begin(),result.begin(),std::multiplies<>());
        return result;
    }

    C operator/(const C& rhs) const{
        C result;
        std::transform(begin(),end(),rhs.begin(),result.begin(),std::divides<>());
        return result;
    }

    C& operator+=(const C& rhs) {
        std::transform(begin(),end(),rhs.begin(),begin(),std::plus<>());
        return static_cast<C&>(*this);
    }

    C& operator-=(const C& rhs) {
        std::transform(begin(),end(),rhs.begin(),begin(),std::minus<>());
        return static_cast<C&>(*this);
    }

    C& operator*=(const C& rhs) {
        std::transform(begin(),end(),rhs.begin(),begin(),std::multiplies<>());
        return static_cast<C&>(*this);
    }

    C& operator/=(const C& rhs) {
        std::transform(begin(),end(),rhs.begin(),begin(),std::divides<>());
        return static_cast<C&>(*this);
    }

    bool operator==(const C& rhs) const {
        return std::equal(begin(),end(),rhs.begin());
    }

    bool operator!=(const C& rhs) const {
        return !std::equal(begin(),end(),rhs.begin());
    }

};
```

And then I updated my structs like this

```
struct RGB : ColorSpace<unsigned char, RGB> {
    union {
        std::array<unsigned char,3> arr;
        struct {
            unsigned char r;
            unsigned char g;
            unsigned char b;
        };
    };
};
```

As you can see I used CRTP to overload operators for each of the color space without much code. I just need to know is my implementation of `struct ColorSpace` the most performant? I need like super-speed. Please note **I use Clang** and target platforms are *iOS* *Android* *Linux*.
P.S. I know that I am doing type-punning here in child structs, but that does not really matter...

Comment: Are you sure about that implementation? It uses a lot of wrapping arithmetic, of course in plain C++ there is not much choice, but in ARM NEON (which you are targeting) there is serious support for saturating arithmetic, which is a reasonable choice when manipulating colors (wrapping looks much worse).

Comment: the thing is that I am not, and I am open to any suggestions. I've had a look into ARM Neon SIMD commands, but after completing their tutorial, I was getting faster results without using neon rather than using...

Comment: link to the tutorial https://developer.arm.com/solutions/os/android/developer-guides/neon-intrinsics-getting-started-on-android

Comment: It is not so straightforward to efficiently implement operations on these small structures, largely because one of them is too few to fill a vector register with, so the vectorization cannot be nicely put into a box and be abstracted away. Naturally I don't know how you wrote that code, but that is a common problem - and of course that can also be reviewed in a separate question.